# SQL to LINQ Conversion of coalesce

Tags: linq, coalesce, sql-to-linq-conversion

**This is my SQL query:**

```
select 
   S.student_No, 
   coalesce(P.Name,'0'),
   P.Surname 
from 
   Person as P 
join 
   Student as S 
       on P.Id = S.Person_Id
```

I want to convert it LINQ , i did it except coalesce function,

```
from P in cbu.PERSON
join S in cbu.STUDENT on P.ID equals S.PERSON_ID
select new
{
     S.Stundent_No,
     P.Name,
     P.Surname,
};
```

how can I use **coalesce** in this linq query

Answer (score 0):

`P.Name ?? "0"`. C# has the coalesce operator built-in. Even if you didn't know that, you could use the `?:` operator.

The join is not necessary, btw. You can just write `P.Student.Stundent_No` (or whatever the properties are called).

Comment: I tried it but i get this error ->  Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Comment: What do you think is the cause of that error message? It is a compiler error.

Comment: i've written instead of P.Name ?? "0",--> PERSON_NAME=P.Name ?? '0' ,  it works but, all null fields become 48 ..

Comment: And also if i write PERSON_NAME=P.Name ?? ' ' like this , at this time all null fields become 32

Comment: Finally it works when i write like this -> PERSON_NAME=P.Name ?? 0

Comment: `''` is a char literal. You want a string literal (`""`).

Comment: It also seems strange that PERSON_NAME is an int?! Why is that? It sounds like a string.